# Change ImagePicker Navigation Title in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

I can't change the `ImagePicker` title in iOS 13. No matter what it's stuck on "Photos". I thought I was doing something wrong until I came across [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122820).

The image picker delegate is set, when I put a break point on whichever line inside the code below it gets hit before the image picker is presented.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    // I tried all of these ** individually **

    viewController.navigationItem.title = "abc"

    imagePicker.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "abc"

    imagePicker.navigationItem.title = "abc"
    
    let controller = navigationController.topViewController
    controller?.navigationItem.title = "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following used to be a working method till iOS 12.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool){
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "abc"
    }
}
```

This no longer seems to be valid. It's either a bug or Apple has removed the ability for others to change the title of the `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: I actually tried that first and it didn't work either. I didn't include it in the question because everything I found on SO said to use the method from the question